# Linking data in from two lists in c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, arraylist

i have information that i have put into two list from a database,
the first list takes in a node object which has attributes ID, LAT and LONG.

Second list has multiple key and values for the each ID in the first list.
the images below illustrate my explanation better.
what I am trying to do is add all those key and values on to the first list for each ID. Any help on how to go about this would be much appreciated.

the information i have put into the two lists.  also these are two lists of objects.

[Image of things in first list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9OQW.png)

[Image of things in second list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M0KT.png)

Essentially one list has primary keys from a table, the second list as foreign keys.
i want to add the second list to the first  in one line
e.g

ID,LAT,LONG,[KEY,VALUE],[KEY,VALUE].... depending on how many there are

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're looking for:

- (1) a SQL query that returns a table in the format `ID, LAT, LONG, [KEY, VALUE], ...` or
- (2) a way to relate the data in these two tables using C# objects.

I'm going to assume the latter.

You could put all those key-value pairs in a `Dictionary<string, string>` inside a `Node` class.

```cs
public class Node
{
    public long ID { get; }
    public int Latitude { get; }
    public int Longitude { get; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> KeyValuePairs { get; }
}

public class KeyValuePair
{
    public long NodeID { get; }
    public string Key { get; }
    public string Value { get; }
}
```

And then iterate through both lists adding the key-value pairs to the Dictionary.

```cs
// Let's suppose we got these populated from the DB
var nodeList = new List<Node>();
var keyValuePairs = new List<KeyValuePair>();

// If we get too many rows from the DB, we'll get better performance by ordering the lists
var orderedNodesArray = nodeList.OrderBy(n => n.ID).ToArray();
var orderedKVPairsArray = keyValuePairs.GroupBy(kv => kv.NodeID).OrderBy(g => g.Key).ToArray();

var i = 0;
var j = 0;
while (i < orderedNodesArray.Length && j < orderedKVPairsArray.Length)
{
    var node = orderedNodesArray[i];
    var kvPair = orderedKVPairsArray[j];

    if (node.ID < kvPair.Key) i++;
    else if (node.ID > kvPair.Key) j++;
    else
    {
        foreach (var kv in kvPair)
            node.KeyValuePairs.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);

        i++;
        j++;
    }
}
```